# Finding MAX() from a serial number field which contains characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has a column `p_no VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL` to store serial number. The format of serial number is `"XXX/0000/18/DEPT"` or `"XX/0001/18/DEPT"`.
I want to retrieve the integer in the serial number to generate another serial number. Can anyone help?

This is the piece of code I started with and got stuck

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING(p_no,0,3) = 'XXX' THEN MAX(SUBSTRING(p_no,4,4)) 
WHEN SUBSTRING(p_no,0,3) = 'XX' THEN MAX(SUBSTRING(p_no,3,4))
END
FROM tbl_project
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(p_no,0,4)
```

Expected result is `"0001"` if values are `"XXX/0000/18/DEPT"` and `"XX/0001/18/DEPT"`

Comment: add expected result

Comment: NB: The first character of a string is position 1 rather than 0.  So `SUBSTRING(p_no,0,3) ` will actaually only give you the first 2 characters of the string. Your comparisons should be `SUBSTRING(p_no,1,3) = 'XXX'` and `SUBSTRING(p_no,1,2) = 'XX'`.  That said, if your `then` logic for both `'XXX'` and `'XX'` is the same (`MAX(SUBSTRING(p_no,4,4))`), you could just use the second condition to cover both scenarios.

Comment: ps. similarly I think for your results you want `substring(p_no,5,4)` rather than `substring(p_no,4,4)`.  When playing with these things, break them down into small testable examples; e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a347cff9de6b9db88e1989688ce83a06

Comment: Consider storing the separate elements in separate columns and only combining them for *display* purposes. That'll make tasks such as this *far* easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to get the value as Integer
CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(p_no, CHARINDEX('/', p_no, 0) + 1, 4))

Since you want the Max, you can use MAX(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(p_no, CHARINDEX('/', p_no, 0) + 1, 4)))

Answer (score 1):

You could use `charindex` to find first position of `/` and if the second part of serial number is fixed, i.e. equals to `4`, which appears to be true, then you could apply `substring` to retrieve it:

```
select serialNo,
       substring(serialNo, charindex('/', serialNo) + 1, 4)
from (
  values ('XXX/0000/18/DEPT'),('XX/0001/18/DEPT')
) a(serialNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want find `MAX` value, then there is no need to group them:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    p_no NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @temp
(
    p_no
)
VALUES
('XXX/0000/18/DEPT'),
('XX/0001/18/DEPT');

SELECT 
MAX( SUBSTRING(t.p_no, charindex('/', t.p_no)+1, 4))
FROM @temp t
```

Output:

```
0001
```