# Selecting a column(char + int combination) based on maximum value in the integer part of the column

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to retrieve a column (`p_no`) value based on the maximum value of the integer part in the column (`p_no`).

The column is having values in the following format `XXX/0000/18/DEPT`
I want to select the column value which is having greater integer part in `SUBSTRING(p_no,4,4)`

I am trying this in MS sql server 2017.
Expected output is the serial_no column value which has greater value after `XXX/` part

Comment: Does `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY SUBSTRING(p_no,4,4) DESC` work?

Comment: yes, it worked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding MAX() from a serial number field which contains characters in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720142/finding-max-from-a-serial-number-field-which-contains-characters-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from MyTable
where cast(substring(p_no,4,4) as int) > serial_no
```

Comment: serial_no column contains chars and integer, can't compare like you said

Comment: @HafisMuhammed So which one is `int` column?? `p_no` or `serial_no` ??

Comment: My bad, there is only one column and it is p_no.